# CrossTab total on the same page?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report with new page Structure like

```
ID 1  (Details for ID1    )
    - CrossTab 1 (new page)
    - CrossTab 2 (new page)

ID 2 (Details for ID2     )
    - CrossTab 1 (new page)
    - CrossTab 2 (new page)
```

I want to display grand total in words (a formula field) for each crosstab on the same page.

Problem I'm having is that the crosstab is in subreport's footer. If I try to insert the 
total in another footer of subreport, the total follows the 2nd crosstab for ID1 which I do not want. Something like this

```
    ID 1  (Details for ID1    )
    - CrossTab 1 (new page)
        - grand Total
    - CrossTab 2 (new page)
        - grand Total

ID 2 (Details for ID2     )
    - CrossTab 1 (new page)
        - grand Total
    - CrossTab 2 (new page)
        - grand Total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading you right, your main report is grouped by {ID}.  In the group footer of {ID}, you have a subreport. In that subreport is the crosstab.  And you want to add a 2nd group footer.

I recommend simplifying your life:

1. Delete the subreport.
2. Recreate your crosstab summary in your main report's Group Footer.
3. Make a 2nd Group Footer section and put your custom string formula there.

The **Section Expert** of your report gives you a variety of options for each section & subection of your report.  Among those options is "New page after", "New page before", and "Keep together".  Play around with those and see if you can get what you want.